# reset input type=range when mouse is released

Tags: javascript, html, input, range

I want to make an easy shuttle-style control to control the playback speed of an external device with.

the idea: user can pull the knob to whatever speed he likes, every statuschange gets sent to the server.
and if i RELEASE the knob, i want it to go back to 0.
Should be pretty easy, so i thought.

everything works, except the release part.

how would you do that?

```
<input id="speed" type="range" min="-16" max="16" value="0" step="1" oninput="changeSpeed(this.value)" onmouseup="resetSpeed()"/>

function changeSpeed(speed) {
    console.log(speed);
    //emit to device
}

function resetSpeed() {
    document.getElementById("speed").value = '0';
}
```

it doesn't work like this.
Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: That should work - http://jsfiddle.net/jqe12843/ - note that the scripts runs in the `<head>` of the document so that the `resetSpeed` function is accessible.

Comment: As Josh Crozier pointed out, you're no doubt forgetting to put your javascript function in the  `<script type="text/javascript">` `</script>` tags

Comment: it actually IS embedded in <script src="/public/javascripts/browser.js"></script>..
and by the way.. that fiddle doesn't work for me either... is there something i might have configured wrong...? (FF35.0.1)

Comment: just tried it in chrome... works like a charm...
how can i make firefox do the same thing?

Comment: also doesn't work on chrome for android :(
is there no way to make this work like it should?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onchange` event-handler instead of `onmouseup`.